# whats the syntax for callable boolean

Tags: java, boolean, callable-object

I have created a callable boolean found from a google search and I want to call it.. What's the syntax? I couldn't find anything useful and I am kinda of a newbie...
Don't mind the code it's just an example

**I want to properly check if something is active from another class**

```
public static class HA implements Callable<Boolean> {
    Socket socket1= null;
    Socket socket2= null;
     ...
    public HA (Socket output) {
        client = output;
        clientt = outpu;
    }

    public Boolean call(boolean isActive) throws Exception {
        String stringExample= "";
        String stringExample2= "";
        ...
```

Comment: You need to instantiate an object of `HA` (`HA ha = new HA();`) and then call the method (`Boolean returned = ha.call(true);`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Executor service to submit the Task

```
//Get ExecutorService from Executors utility class, thread pool size is 10
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
//create a list to hold the Future object associated with Callable
List<Future<Boolean>> list = new ArrayList<>();
//Create Callable instance
Callable<Boolean> callable = new HA(new Socket());
for(int i=0; i< 100; i++){
    //submit Callable tasks to be executed by thread pool
    Future<Boolean> future = executor.submit(callable);
    //add Future to the list, we can get return value using Future
    list.add(future);
}
for(Future<Boolean> fut : list){
    try {
        //print the return value of Future, notice the output delay in console
        // because Future.get() waits for task to get completed
        System.out.println(new Date()+ "::"+fut.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//shut down the executor service now
executor.shutdown();
```

And your Callable could be as below

```
public static class HA implements Callable<Boolean> {
        private Socket client;
        public HA (Socket output) {
            this.client = output;
        }
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            //return the thread name executing this callable task
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A Callable (.call()) is just like a Runnable (.run) that happens to return something instead of void.

If you had used the @Override annotation like you should on the call() method, you would have seen that you didn't override it but ceated another overloaded call(boolean) method which is unrelated to the Callable.call().

You can obviously invoke the .call() method yourself, but usually these Callable objects show up in the context of delegating execution to an Executor (usually one running tha call on another thread and returning a Future).